# Flutter cut rectangle from widget?

Tags: flutter

How can I clip a rectangle from an image/widget?
I want something like this:

[image]

I can add a blur overlay, but I need to "cut" a rectangle in the middle.
How can I do this?

```dart
 Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      LastQrScannerPreview(
        onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
      ),
      Center(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screenshot` plugin to take a screenshot of your widget. The link is below:
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Comment: I don't understand.  I want to create a QR reader layout (as you can see the code above). It works fine: fullscreen camera preview, on top of that there is a full screen blur overlay. I want to cut out a rectangle in the middle of the blur overlay, and add borders, etc...

Comment: I got your point. I this case, you will have to create a custom widget with custom paint.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

Comment: Ok, but still not answering the question, because I need to cut out a rectangle from the center of the BackdropFilter widget

Comment: @CookieMonster add Clip widget with custom clip where you would remove the rect from the center. Will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (Last widget of your stack)

```
Container(
  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 50,
      width: 100,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this inside your stack:

```
Positioned(
  child: Center(
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 250.0,
          height: 250.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.clear,
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            border: BoxBorder.lerp(
              Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), width: 1),
              Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), width: 1),
              .1
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
  )
),
```

This will blur out the background and create a rectangular cutout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.